# Where do I find a mad catz see2 uv150 driver?

Tags: drivers

I have an older mad catz eclipse see2 uv150 adapter from USB to VGA.  I am trying to use it on my system in order to connect it to a vga compatible projector at my church.  I need to install a driver so my system will recognize it.  I can't find a driver that will work.  Each time I try, the archive manager says it cannot open.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
```

Comment: Also see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=988298, http://patentpondering.blogspot.com/2011/02/triton-see2-xtreme-uv200-in-linux.html